# Audio routing on Windows 10 with 2 inputs and 2 outputs

Tags: windows, audio, routing, hdmi, streaming

Have a new setup for streaming and I'm trying to replicate an old routing I had when I was using a single machine. However, I'm now offloading the streaming via HDMI to another machine and I of course want to maintain the same routing.

Here's a (very) bad image of the layout that I had and want to obtain again;

[Routing layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaa5f.png)

I've been using Virtual Audio Cables and the new audio routing settings in Windows 10, but I can't seem to get it working. I have a workaround involving more physical cables but there is a noticeable delay introduced which I would rather do without.

Any suggestions would be helpful! :)

Comment: Have you looked at Voicemeeter Banana? Its a more powerful version of Virtual Cable.

Comment: @Andy yep, that'll do it! Works wonderfully